# How can i display all database records when a activity starts in Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-activity

I have 2 activities. In the first one i have a `button`. When the `button` is pressed, 2 things are happening. The first one, i insert some records in a `mysql` database on a web server and second, i start a new activity. In the second activity, i simply display the database records in a `textView`. When the second activity starts, there are moments in which the last inserted record is displayed, other moments in which is not. I think the second activity starts faster, than the records are inserted into the database and are displayed. What do i need to change, to have all the records displayed, every time the second activity starts?

Comment: Are you using an AsyncTask to do the mysql inserts?

Comment: I'm using `$_POST` in a php file, on the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database query can be done in onResume in Activity

```
new DataDownloader(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

In the AsyncTask , you can query for required data

```
public class DataDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
{

 private ProgressDialog dialog;
public DataDownloader(SplashScreen context){
        this.context=context;

    }
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Syncing Contact data..");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(AppConstants.NETLOG, "" + e.toString());
        }
    }
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Do the required database query
return status;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(!aBoolean){
            //Display error
        }else{
            //Process correct data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since yesterday i trying to solve this problem like this, but i couldn't figure it out. I solved it today by adding a delay when the second activity starts.  So the delay of 1 second is quite enough, to insert and read data from the database. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can start your DB process through implementation like AsyncTask. In onPostExecute you can push your second Activity. That will reduce the risk of hard-coding the delay time as 1 second. This is always dynamic depending on DB.